# What is the source of the electrons, or will it stop working?

Tags: electromagnetism

If you place a metal coil in a vacuum glass container, and approach the coil with a magnet on the opposing side of the glass then I believe that the electrons have the possibility to travel through the glass to an adjacent conductor.  If all of that is true, as electrons leave the wire system I would think it would be an impossibility for it to continue as the wire atoms can only be so electron deficient.  I'm assuming that the magnet would continue to be able to induce some electron un-even distribution in the wire, but the wire no-longer be able to eject them.  In a vacuum, without any further chemistry to be able to supply electrons, there would be a loss of source.

True?

Comment: There is some confusion, only moving charges feel the force of a magnetic field http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/magnetic/forchg.html , and electrons in a conductor are bound

Comment: @annav, it might be a good idea to clarify that.  e.g., what is a "moving charge?"  Moving relative to what?  Certainly waving a magnet past a coil will induce currents in the coil.

Comment: @S.McGrew But  the question is a  fantasy of electrons getting off the surface and penetrating the glass! The electrons in the conductor are bound by the conductor lattice

Comment: @annav, yes, but that's a different issue. I'm disagreeing with your statement that "only moving charges feel the force of a magnetic field."

Comment: @S.McGrew  The way I see it, if you look at the link of the force on a moving charge, the electron has to be moving in order to feel it , in the case of moving the magnet , In the semiclassical picture the velocity will be of conduction band electrons with respect to the magnet.

Comment: Yes, the magnet and the electrons need to be moving relative to each other.  The electrons do not need to be in motion (from an observer's perspective) to experience a force due to a magnet that's moving past them.

Answer (score 0):

A changing magnetic flux through you coil will cause electrons to shift towards one end.  Unless the induced voltage is very high, they are not likely to move off through the vacuum or pass through the non-conducting glass.  A low density gas in the container might allow arcing between the two ends of the coil.